# How to create a notebook element that can replace itself?

Tags: dynamic, notebooks, gui-construction

I would like to create a notebook element that can replace itself.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
Panel[Column[
  {Style["This is a panel", Bold],
   Button["Press me!",
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]; 
    NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     "\"Now I'm just a piece of static text.\""]]}]]
```

This code will create a little panel:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we press the button, the panel will get replaced by a piece of static text (i.e. not a dynamic expression that's shown as text, but just plain old non-dynamic text).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, in this implementation actually it's not the panel that gets replaced, but the complete cell containing the panel, and that's my problem: I need *only the panel* to be replaced, so this will work even if the panel is just a subexpression in a larger expression.

**How can we create an UI control that is able to replace itself with an arbitrary expression in the notebook?**

Comment: This is at least the second time I've read a question without noting the author, and thought "This is probably one for Szabolcs to answer." afterward to see you're *asking*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I thought the same thing.

Comment: @Heike :-) -- can you think of any native object that has the behavior Szabolcs describes?  I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, there is one, and I should have mentioned it!  It is the image cropping GUI.  I'm not sure if it's available in 7.  Paste an image into the notebook, right click, and select Crop Image.  You can adjust the crop boundaries, and double-clicking it will replace the control with the cropped image.  If I remember right, last time I checked this was implemented in terms of an undocumented native control that does almost everything alone, and not in terms of low-level Dynamic constructs.

Comment: Nope, not in v7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I only know of `\\[SelectionPlaceHolder]` to replace bits in a formatted expression, but I don't see how that can be used here.

Comment: I don’t have time to add another answer right now, but this can also be done with the `BoxReference` system to make everything as precise and clean as is possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solution relies on putting a `TagBox` with a custom tag around the part to be replaced, reading the cell and replacing the tag, then writing it back. Personally I've always felt that the need to read the entire cell and write it all again seems kind of clunky, but I don't know of a better way to do this.

```
MakeBoxes[replacementMarker[a_,tag_],StandardForm]^:=TagBox[MakeBoxes[a],tag]

replaceMark[rule_,nb_:EvaluationNotebook[],which_:All,cell_:EvaluationCell]:=(
SelectionMove[nb,which,cell];
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[],NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]/.rule])

Row[{"Not replaced",
replacementMarker[
    Panel[Column[{Style["This is a panel",Bold],Button["Press me!",
    replaceMark[TagBox[_,"replacementTag"] :> MakeBoxes["\" Now I'm just text. \""]]
    ]}]]
,"replacementTag"]
,"Not replaced"}]
```

Important note! The action cannot be undone, so if used for example to allow dynamic reformatting of data or similar, be aware that mistakes can end up deleting the old contents.

Comment: Quite clever! +1

Comment: Thanks. I can't say I like it, it just feels dangerous to be re-writing an entire cell when there's no undo, unless of course the contents aren't important or can be regenerated quickly.

Comment: Just putting it out here that these days you can just do `NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[],NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]]/.rule, None, AutoScroll->False]` without having to move the selection. There should be a way to get the box using ``FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind`` or something but I don't know how.

Comment: Also there's ``FrontEnd`ObjectChildren`` which also lets you find specific boxes of a front-end object, assuming you don't mind searching for the right one.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version of the previous answer that doesn't move the selection and only works at the `Box` level:

```
MakeBoxes[replacementMarker[a_, tag_], StandardForm] ^:=

 TagBox[MakeBoxes[a],
  tag,
  BoxID -> tag]

replaceMark[obj_, function_, tag_] :=
 With[{ref =
    FE`BoxReference[
     FE`Evaluate@obj,
     {{tag}}
     ]
   },
  FrontEndExecute@
   FrontEnd`BoxReferenceReplace[ref,
    FrontEndExecute@
      FrontEnd`BoxReferenceRead[ref] // function
    ]
  ]

Row[{"Not replaced",
  replacementMarker[
   Panel[
    Column[{Style["This is a panel", Bold],
      Button["Press me!",
       replaceMark[
        EvaluationNotebook[],
        MakeBoxes[" Now I'm just text."] &,
        "replacementTag"
        ]
       ]
      }]],
   "replacementTag"],
  "Not replaced"}
 ]
```

It works in exactly the same way, but uses the `` FrontEnd`BoxReference* `` functions as "documented" [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133523/38205)

The nice thing about this is it makes preserving the `TagBox` pretty easy. We just need to use a `BoxOffset` to replace the inner contents:

```
replaceMark[obj_, function_, tag_] :=
 With[{ref =
    FE`BoxReference[
     FE`Evaluate@obj,
     {{tag}},
     FE`BoxOffset -> {FE`BoxChild[1]}
     ]
   },
  FrontEndExecute@
   FrontEnd`BoxReferenceReplace[ref, 
    FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`BoxReferenceRead[ref] // function]
  ]
```

One thing to note when playing with this is that it replaces the next instance of the ID from the current selection, so if you don't delete any replaced cells after your cursor it will seem as if it isn't working. Alternatively provide a UUID to your box:

```
With[{uuid = CreateUUID[]},
 Row[{"Not replaced",
   replacementMarker[
    Panel[
     Column[{
       Style["This is a panel", Bold],
       Button["Press me!",
        replaceMark[EvaluationNotebook[],
         MakeBoxes[uuid] &,
         uuid]
        ]
       }]
     ],
    uuid],
   "Not replaced"}]
 ]
```

We can even stick this in the `MakeBoxes` call:

```
MakeBoxes[replacementMarker[a_], StandardForm] ^:=

  With[{uuid = CreateUUID[]},
   TagBox[MakeBoxes[a] /. FE`$BoxUUID -> uuid,
    uuid,
    BoxID -> uuid
    ]
   ];
With[{uuid = CreateUUID[]},
 Row[{"Not replaced",
   replacementMarker[
    Panel[
     Column[{
       Style["This is a panel", Bold],
       Button["Press me!",
        replaceMark[
         EvaluationNotebook[],
         MakeBoxes[FE`$BoxUUID] &,
         FE`$BoxUUID
         ]
        ]
       }]
     ]],
   "Not replaced"}]
 ]
```

Now any raw `replacementMarker` will make itself unique with the ID being propagated down via `` FE`$BoxUUID `` with the UUID being preserved after replacement.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to click on a structure somewhere and have it get replaced, you could use [`EvaluationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationBox):

```
{
a,
Button[
    Panel@Column[{Style["This is a panel",Bold],"Press me!"}],
    NotebookWrite[EvaluationBox[], "\"Now I'm just a piece of static text.\""],
    Appearance->None
],
b
}
```

[image]

After clicking it looks like:

> {a, "Now I'm just a piece of static text.", b}

If you want to click on a button, and have some parent structure get replaced, you could use [`ParentBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParentBox) + [`EvaluationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationBox):

```
{
a,
Panel@Column[{
    Style["This is a panel",Bold],
    Button[
        "Press me!",
        NotebookWrite[
            ParentBox@ParentBox@ParentBox@EvaluationBox[],
            "\"Now I'm just a piece of static text.\""
        ]
    ]
}],
b
}
```

[image]

After clicking:

> {a, "Now I'm just a piece of static text.", b}