# What is the complete list of valid FrontEnd Packet types?

Tags: front-end, mathlink-or-wstp, undocumented

In response to my question [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121) John Fultz answered with a method using the hilariously named `` FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket ``.

What is the complete list of such Packets?

---

Related:

- [Items known by CurrentValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/121)
- [What is the complete list of valid Front End Tokens?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/121)

Comment: @John I didn't know you were here.  Would you like to answer instead, and I'll delete mine?

Comment: Your answer is fine.  And...the list that command returns *is* exhaustive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Once again thanks to John Fultz [we know a command](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6583176#6583176) that returns the complete list of these packets:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket[]][[1, 1, 4]]
```

Results from *Mathematica* 7:

```
""
"Null"
"CompoundExpression"
"List"
"Execute"
"FrontEndExecute"
"KernelExecute"
"OpenParallelLinksPacket"
"KernelStartupCompleted"
"ReassignInputNamePacket"
"InputNamePacket"
"OutputNamePacket"
"ReturnTextPacket"
"ReturnInputFormPacket"
"ReturnPacket"
"TextPacket"
"DisplayPacket"
"DisplayEndPacket"
"SyntaxPacket"
"InputPacket"
"InputStringPacket"
"ExperimentalInputMouseCoordinatesPacket"
"MenuPacket"
"MessagePacket"
"ConsoleMessagePacket"
"PrintTemporaryPacket"
"SuspendPacket"
"ResumePacket"
"BeginDialogPacket"
"EndDialogPacket"
"EvaluatorStart"
"EvaluatorQuit"
"EvaluatorInterrupt"
"EvaluatorAbort"
"EvaluatorHalt"
"EnterSubsession"
"ExitSubsession"
"Forward"
"ForwardEvaluate"
"ForwardedData"
"CompletionsListPacket"
"SpellingSuggestionsPacket"
"NotebookResetGeneratedCells"
"DontNotebookResetGeneratedCells"
"BeginFrontEndInteractionPacket"
"EndFrontEndInteractionPacket"
"DisplaySetSizePacket"
"DisplayFlushImagePacket"
"FlushPrintOutputPacket"
"FrontEndToken"
"SetFileLoadingContext"
"Version"
"VersionNumber"
"DefaultFormatTypeForStyle"
"Notebooks"
"SelectedNotebook"
"SetSelectedNotebook"
"InputNotebook"
"EvaluationNotebook"
"SetEvaluationNotebook"
"ButtonNotebook"
"ClipboardNotebook"
"MessagesNotebook"
"HelpBrowserNotebook"
"DefaultHelpViewerNotebook"
"DebuggerContinue"
"DebuggerContinueToSelection"
"DebuggerSelect"
"DebuggerSetStackList"
"DebuggerSetExpressionColoring"
"DebuggerGetSelectionInformation"
"DebuggerAddBreakpoint"
"DebuggerRemoveBreakpoint"
"DebuggerEnableBreakpoint"
"DebuggerDisableBreakpoint"
"DebuggerSetAutoContinueBreakpoint"
"DebuggerSetNoAutoContinueBreakpoint"
"DebuggerSetBreakOnAssignmentWatchpoint"
"DebuggerSetNoBreakOnAssignmentWatchpoint"
"DebuggerSetBreakOnEvaluationWatchpoint"
"DebuggerSetNoBreakOnEvaluationWatchpoint"
"DebuggerSetBreakOnFunctionWatchpoint"
"DebuggerSetNoBreakOnFunctionWatchpoint"
"DebuggerToolsNotebook"
"DebuggerStackNotebook"
"DebuggerBreakpointsNotebook"
"EvaluationCell"
"ButtonCell"
"NotebookCreate"
"NotebookCreateReturnObject"
"NotebookOpen"
"NotebookOpenReturnObject"
"NotebookLocate"
"NotebookLocateReturnResult"
"SystemOpen"
"HelpBrowserLookup"
"HelpBrowserLookupReturnResult"
"HelpBrowserGetListBoxList"
"HelpBrowserSetListBoxItem"
"NotebookClose"
"NotebookSave"
"NotebookSaveAs"
"NotebookConvert"
"NotebookPrint"
"NotebookImage"
"ToExpression"
"NotebookPut"
"NotebookPutReturnObject"
"NotebookGet"
"NotebookRead"
"NotebookWrite"
"NotebookApply"
"CellPrint"
"NotebookDelete"
"NotebookFind"
"NotebookFindReturnObject"
"SelectionMove"
"SelectionCreateCell"
"SelectionCellCreateCell"
"SelectionDuplicateCell"
"SelectionEvaluate"
"SelectionEvaluateCreateCell"
"SelectionEvaluateApply"
"FileBrowse"
"DirectoryBrowse"
"ChooseColor"
"RecordSound"
"Options"
"FullOptions"
"AbsoluteOptions"
"LocalOptions"
"LocalAbsoluteOptions"
"SetOptions"
"RemoveOptions"
"SetLocalOptions"
"SaveConversionOptions"
"RestoreConversionOptions"
"SelectionSetStyle"
"CallPacket"
"Value"
"SetValue"
"Select2DTool"
"Select3DTool"
"Argument"
"SetArgument"
"ChildObject"
"ObjectChildren"
"ObjectChildCount"
"NextSiblingObject"
"PreviousSiblingObject"
"ParentObject"
"SelectObject"
"SelectedObject"
"OutputCellObject"
"ObjectGet"
"ObjectPut"
"NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates"
"NotebookResumeScreenUpdates"
"NotebookUpdateScreen"
"SelectNamedObject"
"ReadNamedObject"
"ReplaceNamedObject"
"SelectionApply"
"SelectionCellsMap"
"SelectionCellContentsMap"
"EvaluatePacket"
"SetKernelSymbolContexts"
"UpdateKernelSymbolContexts"
"SetFunctionInformation"
"UpdateDynamicObjects"
"UpdateDynamicObjectsSynchronous"
"AddVariableDefiningFunctions"
"AddUsedToGenerateSideEffectGraphicsFunctions"
"AddFunctionTemplateInformationToFunctions"
"AddOptionInformationToFunctions"
"ControllerBindingsInOutput"
"ReturnDynamicOutput"
"NotebookInformation"
"CellInformation"
"ToFileName"
"SetPersistentFrontEnd"
"GetMenusPacket"
"ResetMenusPacket"
"AddFileBrowserFilterPacket"
"OpenFunctionInspectorPacket"
"GetErrorsInSelectionPacket"
"ErrorIconIsDisplayedPacket"
"UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket"
"UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket"
"UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket"
"UndocumentedBoxStatisticsPacket"
"UndocumentedHangFrontEndPacket"
"UndocumentedCrashFrontEndPacket"
"UndocumentedGetNGraphicsImagePacket"
"UndocumentedGetBoxTypesPacket"
"UndocumentedWhyTheBeepText"
"ReparseBoxStructurePacket"
"AddBoxIDs"
"SetBoxIDs"
"GetBoxIDs"
"RemoveBoxIDs"
"BoxReferenceExists"
"BoxReferenceFind"
"BoxReferenceRead"
"BoxReferenceReplace"
"BoxReferenceSetOptions"
"BoxReferenceGetOptions"
"UndocumentedProtoTypeBuild"
"ImportToNotebook"
"ConvertToPostScriptPacket"
"ConvertToPostScriptPacket2"
"VerboseConvertToPostScriptPacket"
"ConvertToBitmapPacket"
"VerboseConvertToBitmapPacket"
"ExportPacket"
"GetLinebreakInformationPacket"
"GetPageBreakInformationPacket"
"GetSelectionBoundingBoxes"
"GetBoundingBoxSizePacket"
"NotebookSetupLayoutInformationPacket"
"NotebookGetLayoutInformationPacket"
"NotebookGetFontParametersPacket"
"NotebookGetMisspellingsPacket"
"InputToBoxFormPacket"
"ExpressionPacket"
"ReturnExpressionPacket"
"CreatePalettePacket"
"SetNotebookStatusLine"
"SetBoxFormNamesPacket"
"NeedCurrentFrontEndPackagePacket"
"NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket"
"SpeakTextPacket"
"SetSpeechParametersPacket"
"CurrentlySpeakingPacket"
"BeepPacket"
"PlaySoundPacket"
"PlaySoundFilePacket"
"TimeConstrained"
"MemoryConstrained"
"GetFrontEndOptionsDataPacket"
"TemplateTooltipPacket"
"GetCellTagsPacket"
"AddEvaluatorNames"
"AddMenuCommands"
"AddDefaultFontProperties"
"NotebookReleaseHold"
"NotebookDynamicToLiteral"
"NotebookCreateDynamicCaches"
"SelectionAddCellTags"
"SelectionRemoveCellTags"
"SelectionAnimate"
"RegisterConverter"
"ParseFileToLinkPacket"
"DebugTooltipPacket"
"CursorTooltipPacket"
"Install"
"SetJavaParameter"
"FindFileOnPath"
"GetFunctionCategories"
"CopyToClipboard"
"SimulateMouseMove"
"SimulateMouseClick"
"SimulateMouseDrag"
"SimulateKeyPress"
"SimulatedEventPending"
"AttachWindow"
"DetachWindow"
"AttachedWindowRequestingModality"
"AttachedWindowReleasingModality"
"MLFS`Put"
"MLFS`PutAppend"
"MLFS`Get"
"MLFS`OpenRead"
"MLFS`OpenWrite"
"MLFS`OpenAppend"
"MLFS`Close"
"MLFS`StreamPosition"
"MLFS`SetStreamPosition"
"MLFS`Read"
"MLFS`WriteString"
"MLFS`URLDownload"
"MLFS`FileNames"
"MLFS`CopyFile"
"MLFS`RenameFile"
"MLFS`DeleteFile"
"MLFS`FileByteCount"
"MLFS`FileDate"
"MLFS`SetFileDate"
"MLFS`FileType"
"MLFS`CreateDirectory"
"MLFS`DeleteDirectory"
"MLFS`RenameDirectory"
"MLFS`CopyDirectory"
"UpdateNewPrimitiveStyle"
"Plugin`NewNotebook"
"Plugin`OpenNotebook"
"Plugin`CloseNotebook"
"Plugin`Quit"
"Plugin`AssignParent"
"Plugin`SizeNotebook"
"Plugin`RedrawNotebook"
"Plugin`GetContextMenuForNotebook"
```

Missing from 10.0.2 that were present in 7:

```
"ButtonCell"
"Plugin`GetContextMenuForNotebook"
"Plugin`RedrawNotebook"
```

Present in 10.0.2 and not in 7:

```
"ActivateLicense"
"ApplyStyle"
"AttachCell"
"AttachedCellParent"
"Bib`ChooseCitationStylePacket"
"Bib`DeleteBibliographyPacket"
"Bib`DeleteCitationsPacket"
"Bib`InsertBibliographyPacket"
"Bib`InsertCitationPacket"
"Bib`InsertNotePacket"
"Bib`InsertSpecificCitationPacket"
"Bib`QueryCitationsPacket"
"Bib`QueryCitationStylesPacket"
"Bib`QueryNoteStylesPacket"
"Bib`RebuildBibliographyPacket"
"Bib`RebuildCitationsPacket"
"Bib`RefreshCitationsPacket"
"Bib`RefreshCitationStylesPacket"
"Bib`SetBibNoteStylePacket"
"Bib`SetCitationStylePacket"
"Boxes"
"BoxReferenceBoxObject"
"CA`QueryAutocompletionPacket"
"CDFDeploy"
"CDFInformation"
"Cells"
"CryptoHash"
"DetachCell"
"ErrorMessage"
"EvaluationBox"
"FinishStartup"
"FlushTextResourceCaches"
"ForwardAndHandle"
"GetMouseAppearance"
"LinguisticTranslateCellPacket"
"NewVersionAction"
"NewVersionAvailable"
"NotebookEvaluate"
"NotebookEvaluateReturn"
"NotebookPredictions"
"OptionCompletionsListPacket"
"OptionValuesCompletionsListPacket"
"ParentBox"
"ParentCell"
"ParentNotebook"
"PastePrediction"
"Plugin`KeyDown"
"Plugin`KeyUp"
"Plugin`MouseDown"
"Plugin`MouseMove"
"Plugin`MouseUp"
"Plugin`NotebookFileError"
"Plugin`OpenNotebookStream"
"Plugin`Print"
"Plugin`Save"
"Plugin`SetActiveWindow"
"Plugin`SetViewRegion"
"Plugin`UpdateScrollPosition"
"Plugin`UpdateScrollPositionRelative"
"RewriteExpressionPacket"
"SampleStyle"
"SelectionSetInlineCellOptions"
"SelectionSetPointStyle"
"SelectionSetRectangleRoundingRadius"
"SetMouseAppearance"
"SetNotebookInList"
"StartTaskTiming"
"StartupAction"
"StopTaskTiming"
"SuppressGraphicsHighlight"
"TemplateCachePacket"
"TickleActivation"
"WindowsCodePage"
"WolframCloud`AssignCloudObject"
"WolframCloud`AutomaticCloudLogin"
"WolframCloud`ConnectionAuthorized"
"WolframCloud`ConnectionCancelled"
"WolframCloud`ConnectionEstablished"
"WolframCloud`ConnectionFailed"
"WolframCloud`ConnectionInitiated"
"WolframCloud`ConnectionTerminated"
"WolframCloud`TaskInformation"
"WolframCloud`UploadComplete"
"WolframCloud`UploadFailed"
"WolframCloud`UploadInitiated"
```

Missing from 11.0.1 that were present in 10.0.2:

```
"AttachedWindowReleasingModality"
"AttachedWindowRequestingModality"
"AttachWindow"
"DetachWindow"
"ExperimentalInputMouseCoordinatesPacket"
"GetFunctionCategories"
"HelpBrowserGetListBoxList"
"HelpBrowserLookup"
"HelpBrowserLookupReturnResult"
"HelpBrowserNotebook"
"HelpBrowserSetListBoxItem"
"SelectionAnimate"
```

Several of these removed packets were for pre-version-6 features. SelectionAnimate is for [animating a cell group](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111463/12) and the HelpBrowserLookup packets are for opening the v5-style help browser, which was still available in v10 but removed from v11.

Present in 11.0.1 but not in 10.0.2

```
"CA`CADumpTriePacket"
"FromFileNameString"
"NotebookGetMisspellingsInStringPacket"
"NotebookGetSpellingSuggestionsPacket"
"NotebookToString"
"RemoveMenuCommands"
"WolframCloud`GenerateFileName"
"WolframCloud`GetAuthentication"
"WolframCloud`Logout"
```

Comment: Do you have any advice on figuring out how these are used? Many seem to have made their way into top-level symbols (for example there is ``System`GetMenusPacket``) but it's unclear how they are used. A simple ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd@GetMenusPacket[]`` has no effect.

Comment: @MB1965 Sorry, I don't.  I have figured out a few by sheer luck I think, but most of the time I have to see it used somewhere.  Try a plain text search of all the files in the *Mathematica* installation directory; sometimes you get lucky.

Answer (score 19):

I thought I'd keep a running tally of what I know about these packets (excluding the obvious ones like `CreatePalettePacket`) just for reference.

---

### Text / Box interchange

#### ReparseBoxStructurePacket

This one parses a string (as far as I can tell just a string) into a box structure. We can use this to, for example, parse out the string which comes as the last output of `NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket` and convert it directly to a box expression:

```
Cell[
  BoxData@
   FrontEndExecute[
    FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket[
     FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket[] // 
      Last]],
  "Output"
  ] // CellPrint
```

#### ExportPacket

This one is enormously useful. I first saw it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/38205).

The basic usage is:

```
ExportPacket[
 expr:_Cell|_Notebook,
 fmt_,
 opts___?OptionQ
 ]
```

You can also call it like:

```
ExportPacket[
 expr:_Cell|_Notebook,
 fmt_,
 file_
 opts___?OptionQ
 ]
```

in which case it dumps to a file.

You can learn more about the supported formats [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-a-selected-cell-as-plain-text/1411#comment3519_1411) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165065/38205)

### GetBoundingBoxSizePacket

This computes the display size of `Cell` expressions. It's just called as:

```
FrontEnd`GetBoundingBoxSizePacket[c_Cell]
```

It returns the horizontal size, the vertical content size, and what I believe is the vertical content padding as its third result. I use it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166771/38205) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166772/38205)

---

### Syntax-coloring

#### UpdateKernelSymbolContexts

Used to set symbol coloring in the FE. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146279/38205) for more info

#### AddUsedToGenerateSideEffectGraphicsFunctions

This tells the front end that this function used to generate side effects, back when `Graphics` were side effects.

It's used like:

```
FrontEnd`AddUsedToGenerateSideEffectGraphicsFunctions[
 {
  {context1, 
   {
    function1,
    function2,
    ...
    }
   },
  {context2, 
   {
    function3,
    function4,
    ...
    }
   },
  ...
  }
 ]
```

As an example you can try:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`AddUsedToGenerateSideEffectGraphicsFunctions[
  {
   {"Global`", {"notARealGraphics"}}
   }
  ]
```

And now if you type:

```
notARealGraphics[];
```

that final semicolon will be colored red

#### AddOptionInformationToFunctions

This is used like `AddUsedToGenerateSideEffectGraphicsFunctions`:

```
FrontEnd`AddOptionInformationToFunctions[
 {
  {context1, 
   {
    {function1, {opName1, ...}},
    {function2, {opName2, ...}},
    ...
    }
   },
  {context2, 
   {
    {function3, {opName3, ...}},
    {function4, {opName4, ...}}
    ...
    }
   },
  ...
  }
 ]
```

Here's an example:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`AddOptionInformationToFunctions[
  {
   {
    "Global`", 
    {
     {"func", {"a", "b", "c"}}
     }
    }
   }
  ]
```

`func[notABOrC->]` will then have `notABOrC` colored red. This is clearly how [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) `"OptionNames"` work.

---

### Autocompletion

#### CA`CADumpTriePacket

Seems to extract data from an autocompletion .trie file:

Used like

```
FrontEndExecute@
 CA`CADumpTriePacket[trieFile]
```

e.g.:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 CA`CADumpTriePacket@First@
  FileNames["*.trie", 
   PacletFind["AutoCompletionData"][[1]]["Location"], Infinity][[1]]
```

**BEWARE**: If the file isn't a properly formatted trie file this *will* crash your system.

---

### Resource finding

#### FindFileOnPath

Used as:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath[
  fileName,
  path
  ]
```

Where `path` is one of:

```
{
 "AddOnHelpPath",
 "AutoloadPath",
 "CharacterEncodingsPath",
 "ConfigurationPath",
 "ConvertersPath",
 "NotebookPath",
 "NotebookSecurityOptionsTrustedPath",
 "NotebookSecurityOptionsUntrustedPath",
 "PalettePath",
 "PreferencesPath",
 "PrivatePathsAFM",
 "PrivatePathsAutoCompletionData",
 "PrivatePathsBitmaps",
 "PrivatePathsFonts",
 "PrivatePathsSystemResources",
 "PrivatePathsTextResources",
 "PrivatePathsTranslationData",
 "SpellingDictionariesPath",
 "StyleSheetPath",
 "SystemHelpPath"
 }
```

**Beware**: *if you provide the wrong path it crashes Mathematica instantly*

Note that `path` can be things built from `FileNameJoin`.

---

### Box edits

#### BoxReference

There's a collection of edit mechanisms predicated on `` FrontEnd`BoxReference* `` packets.

These all use `` FE`BoxReference `` (as far as I've seen). The standard usage of this as I've seen looks like:

```
FE`BoxReference[obj,
 {{id}},
 FE`SearchStart->startspec
 FE`BoxOffset->{offset}
 ]
```

Where the options can be dropped.

- `obj` as far as I can tell is a `NotebookObject`, `CellObject`, or `BoxObject`, but you can also get the current spec from from `` FE`Evaluate@FEPrivate`Self[] ``
- The `id` searches for `BoxID->id`. It can also be `` FE`Parent[id] ``. I don't know what that does.
- The offset should look like `` FE`BoxChild[n] `` or `` FE`BoxParent[n] ``.
- The only `SearchStart` values I've seen are `"StartFromBeginning"` and `"StartFromFirstDockedCell"`.

Here are some usages:

- `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceBoxObject `` (`BoxReferenceBoxObject[boxref]`)

  finds the `BoxObject` for `` FE`BoxReference ``
- `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceRead `` (`BoxReferenceRead[boxref]`)

  reads the `BoxObject` for `` FE`BoxReference ``
- `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind `` (`BoxReferenceFind[boxref]`)

  Selects the `BoxObject` for `` FE`BoxReference ``
- `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceReplace `` (`BoxReferenceReplace[boxref,boxes]`)

  Replaces the `BoxObject` for `` FE`BoxReference ``
- `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceGetOptions `` (`BoxReferenceGetOptions[boxref, ops]`?)

  I don't actually know how this one works
- `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceSetOptions `` (`BoxReferenceSetOptions[boxref, ops]`?)

  Same here

---

### Keyboard Input

#### SimulateKeyPress

This one is weird and I don't really understand it. We'll start with the basic usage:

```
FrontEndExecute@
  FrontEnd`SimulateKeyPress[
   keys:_String|_Symbol|_Integer
   ];
```

Any `Symbol` passed is simply converted to its fully qualified string form (except for `` System` `` level symbols which simply take their `SymbolName`), the same is true for integers.

The system then simulates a key press for each character in the string. What is odd is that the characters either all come out as if Shift was held or in their lower-case form. That is, the `$FrontEndSession` will either come out as `$FRONTENDSESSION` or as `4frontendsession`. I have been unable to figure out what decides this.

Note that holding a modifier has the same effect as if one was typing.

On top of the weirdness with capitalization, there is a second valid usage form:

```
FrontEndExecute@
  FrontEnd`SimulateKeyPress[
   keys:_String|_Symbol|_Integer,
   list_List,
   ___
   ];
```

Note that having anything other than a list in the second position does nothing. Oddly, though, I can't figure out what that list is for. Initially I had assumed it was a list of modifier keys. But no set of modifier key strings seems to do anything. In fact I can't find any effect whatsoever of having anything in that list. Note that any argument can follow that list, though. But that second position list is clearly important for something. I just cannot figure out what.

---

### Cursor click/options

#### SimulateMouseMove / SimulateMouseDrag / SimulateMouseClick

`SimulateMouseMove` moves the mouse to a given screen position. Have yet to find a use for it, but it does allow one to play tricks on a user by putting something like:

```
Dynamic[
 FrontEndExecute@
  FrontEnd`SimulateMouseMove[
   $FrontEndSession,
   MousePosition[]
   ],
 UpdateInterval -> 0
 ]
```

in a notebook. There might be an option for moving to a certain named position, e.g., `Center` but I haven't found it. I just wrote that into a wrapper function.

`SimulateMouseDrag` and `SimulateMouseClick` are similarly obvious:

`SimulateMouseDrag` takes a list of positions `{start, end}` and simulates a mouse drag between the two.

`SimulateMouseClick` just clicks on a position.

A sample usage:

```
FrontEndExecute@{
  FrontEnd`SimulateMouseDrag[
    $FrontEndSession,
    {{1200, 30}, {1200, 50}}
    ],
  FrontEnd`SimulateMouseClick[
    $FrontEndSession,
    {1200, 50}
    ]
  }
```

On my Mac, with screen rectangle of `{{4, 1440}, {23, 900}}` this drags a window docked at the top right corner down 20 points.

The click is necessary, I found, to get the OS to recognize the mouse drag.

#### SetMouseAppearance

`` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`SetMouseAppearance[expr_]] `` sets the mouse appearance

#### FindAndClickDefaultButton / FindAndClickCancelButton

See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153096/38205)

These find and click the first button with `"ButtonType" -> "Cancel"` or `"ButtonType" -> "Default"` in the [`Appearance` list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134779/38205).

---

### Attached cells

#### AttachedCellParent

This is exactly what you'd expect. Except for 1 big warning. If the [`CellObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellObject.html) no longer exists it'll crash Mathematica.

#### AttachCell / DetachCell

Found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99322/38205)

Used as

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`AttachCell[obj: (_CellObject | _BoxObject | _NotebookObject),
  cellExpr_,
  {
   radialDistanceFromAnchor: (_Integer | _Scaled | "InlineContents"),
   alignment: {Center | Left | Right, Center | Bottom | Top } | "EndOfContents"
   },
  anchor:
   {
    Center | Left | Right | _Scaled | _Integer | _Real | Baseline, 
    Center | Bottom | Top | _Scaled | _Integer | _Real | Baseline
    },
  "ClosingActions"->
   {
    (
     "ParentChanged" | "EvaluatorQuit" |
     "OutsideMouseClick" | "SelectionDeparture" | "MouseExit"|
     "CellGroupOpened"| "CellGroupClosed" ) ...
     }
  ]
```

From Kuba, when attaching to a notebook using the `"ParentChanged"` setting will crash Mathematica as detailed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134768/5478). This also happens when using it with the `"InlineContents"` and `"EndOfContents"` anchor and alignments.

`` FrontEnd`DetachCell `` simply detaches an attached cell.

---

### Menu edits

#### AddMenuCommands

Described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/915/38205)

Used as

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[menu,{items}]
```

where `menu` is the target menu and `items` are `MenuItem`/`Item` expressions or `Delimiter.

See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6227/38205

Which shows how to do this with a `"MenuList*"` menu.

#### ResetMenusPacket

This can be used to both reset the menus and set an arbitrary `Menu` structure.

Used as:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 ResetMenusPacket[{menu}]
```

where `menu` is either a `Menu` expression looking like

```
Menu["Mathematica", {menu_items_and_submenus}]
```

or `Automatic` as far as I've discovered. I'm sure there are more use cases but these are the ones I've found.

More info [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133851/what-are-all-the-possible-menu-edits)

---

### Cell Groups

#### SetCellGroupOpen

In the `` "FEPrivate`" `` context. Allows one to set the open/close state of a cell group. Called like:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd@
 FrontEnd`Value@
  FEPrivate`SetCellGroupOpen[
   cell,
   Open|Close|True|False
   ]
```

`Open/True` and `Close/False` are the same thing.

Any other spec will return `$Failed` (which prevents it from being used to set up `Dynamic` open/closers)

---

### Obvious but useful

#### NotebookGetLayoutInformation

Provides useful information for anyone working with writing papers in mathematica as it gives access to cell sizes and page break info.

#### NotebookDynamicToLiteral

Converts the current dynamic selection to its static displayed form.

#### SelectObject

Moves the selection to a given FE object

#### SelectedObject

`` FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`SelectedObject[nb] `` returns whatever objects are selected in a notebook

#### ObjectChildren

Provides access to the object hierarchy in a notebook. Particularly useful for getting the boxes in a given cell / box. At the `$FrontEnd` level though this will give you *all* notebooks which is useful in and of itself.

---

## A note on GetFEKernelInit

A large amount of useful functionality is hidden in here which I simply haven't gotten around to investigating. For example there's this:

```
System`DeclareKnownSymbols[l_] :=
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
  FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
   $Context, FrontEnd`Private`ResolvedContextPath[], 
   {{$Context, {}, {}, l, {}}}]
  ]
```

which includes that `` FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts `` which had been crashing my copy of Mathematica repeatedly

You can find the file by:

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath[
  "GetFEKernelInit.tr",
  "PrivatePathsTextResources"
 ]
```

---

## Warning

Lots of these crash the system if used improperly. For example a bare `` FrontEnd`UpdateDynamicObjects `` or `` FrontEnd`UpdateDynamicObjectsSynchronous `` will crash the system. You have to pass it the results from `` Internal`GetTrackChanges `` (e.g. `` Dynamic[a++; Internal`GetTrackChanges[]] ``) which seems to be the Box ID number.

Comment: @Kuba I haven't had time to get back to this. `SimulateKeyPress` seems to be a more complicated beast than the others. Sometimes it outputs as if Shift is held and sometimes not. As the person who spelunked out `AttachCell` you might know better how to deal figure out why it does this.

Comment: I used this reparsing once, for polishing my mindless approach to metaprogramming: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89892/5478

Comment: Thank you a lot, guys. A really great concentration of information I was looking for a long time. Thank you Mr. Wizard, thank you b3m2a1, thank you Kuba. Voted all up!