# Bug appears when re-installing Mathematica

Tags: bugs

I have recently re-installed *Mathematica 11.2.0* on my machine due to its slow performance and I have encountered a bug (?). From this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55405/the-front-end-encountered-an-error-while-processing-a-notebookpredictions-pack) it appears to be an old bug on MMA 10. I somewhat have an idea from what the problem is generated. Basically, when I start Mathematica and evaluate a command of the form `$"Comand Here"` (ex:`$Version` or `$LicenseID`) it works perfectly, however, after evaluating this command, when I close the notebook, I get the error:

> The front end encountered an error while processing a "NotebookPredictions" packet.

This appears only on this circumstance.

I want to add that this did not happen on my previous install, and I already tried re-installing the software but this problem keeps on persisting. I do not understand why.

Comment: (note that you shouldn't use the tag "bugs" --- see its description)

Comment: @anderstood if you look at the link that I posted, it is agreed that it is a bug. In this case, why wouldn't the tag "bugs" fit?

Comment: The rule I have come to learned is that someone *other* than the original poster will edit the question and add the bugs tag once consensus is reached.

Comment: So have you disabled the Suggestion Bar?

Comment: I've had this problem too. It happens whenever the input and output cells are deleted before the suggestions bar has time to appear. [It is easily reproducible](https://gfycat.com/GrayFortunateBellfrog) by running any command and then quickly deleting the input and output.