# Animations in 5.2

Tags: animation, version-5

I have to do an activity with students in a laboratory where only Mathematica 5.2 is available .

I would to do some animations, but in 5.2, from what I understand, I should select the series of graphics produced by `Animation`, or by some other means, and type Ctrl-Y.

Is there some way to automate this process to obtain an animation similar to what is available in later versions of Mathematica?

Comment: one way would be to upgrade Mathematica in laboratory.

Comment: I am thinking of something like  

    `Animate[g[ω], {ω, 1, 2}]  
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell]  
    SelectionAnimate[EvaluationNotebook[]]`

Comment: @garej: would be nice, but it's out of my control.

Comment: Not an answer, but I personally miss the ease of Ctrl-Y animations.

Comment: I didn't read your comment, it seems you already have most of what I wrote figured out ...

Comment: I'm truly impressed at the number of people who have copies of V5.2 around to test the answers.

Comment: Maybe `<<Version5\`Graphics\`` can be used for tests?

Comment: There's also a documentation page of [`SelectionAnimate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectionAnimate.html) with a useful example, however it doesn't work with Mathematica 10 and I can't tell if it works in 5.2.

Comment: @Brett, the old versions have their charms. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have version 5.2, and this type of animation no longer works properly in version 9, which is the oldest version I have installed.  So what I show below is *only an untested starting point* for something more robust.  I hope it will be helpful.

```
animate[frames_] := Module[{},
  Scan[Show, frames];
  SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, CellGroup];
  FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"];
  FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionAnimate"]
]
```

`frames` must be a list of graphics, e.g.

```
frames = Table[
   Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, 1]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}];

animate[frames]
```

As I remember in v5.2 `Show` caused the graphics to be rendered into a new cell, but I may be wrong ... in v6 and later this would be `Print`, which I used to test this (sort of, my notebook display gets corrupted when I try it in v9/v10 ...)

Comment: I added small corrections to make it run correctly (`Circle` apparently doesn't use defaults in version 5.2).

Comment: Tested it on 5.2; works well.

Answer (score 5):

What I did back in the day instead of explicitly loading `` Graphics`Animation`​ `` was to use either of `Table[]` or `Do[]`, depending on whether I was interested in further exporting the animation to a GIF or not. Since graphics in old *Mathematica* was a side effect (hence the need for the old `DisplayFunction` gymnastics), one merely collapsed the set of pictures thus produced, and then double-clicked on the cell group if one wants to see the animation.

Thankfully, this machine I'm using has 5.2, so I can show an example:

[image: an animation in 5.2]

Notice the six tiny buttons in the lower left? Those controls show up after double-clicking the group of graphics cells. Most people now might not be able to guess what the second button did: it allowed one to run the animation forwards first, as usual, and then backwards. Nowadays one now has to do something like `ListAnimate[Join[#, Reverse[Most[#]]] & @ list]` for this.

Comment: There's a button on an `Animator` to toggle play direction. Clicking it three times gives for "forwards-then-backwards" if I remember it correctly. Presumably that corresponds to an `Animate` option.

Answer (score 1):

In his book "The Mathematica Guidebook for Graphics", which was written at the time of Mathematica 5, Michael Trott gives a lot of examples of animations. His technique was to create a separate notebook for each animation and to launch the notebook with :

```
FrontEndExecute[{
      FrontEnd`NotebookLocate[
   FrontEnd`FileName[{"Animations"}, "2_1_TreeOfPythagoras.nb"]]}]
```

This assumes that the target notebook is "./Animations/2_1_TreeOfPythagoras.nb"

This code of Trott his hided in the style of the some buttons that permit to a user to launch the animation.

*I have not tested this code*