# How to get the size of a DateObject?

Tags: gui-construction, date-and-time

`DateObject`s can be of varying physical dimensions.

```
CurrentDate[Today, #] & /@ {"Day", "Month", "Year"}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

How do you get the size of a `DateObject`?  I tried `AbsoluteOptions[Today]` but it returns unevaluated.  Ideas?

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158821/38205

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it entirely in the FE (i.e. without a full `Rasterize` call, which is done in the FE anyway):

```
getBoxSize[c_Cell] :=
  {#[[1]], Total@#[[2 ;;]]} &@First@
    FrontEndExecute@GetBoundingBoxSizePacket[c];
getBoxSize[e_] := getBoxSize[Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[e]]]

getBoxSize@CurrentDate[#] & /@ {"Day", "Month", "Year"}

{{148., 25.}, {121., 25.}, {90., 25.}}
```

Note that this is much faster than using a raw `Rasterize`:

```
getBoxSize@CurrentDate[#] & /@ {"Day", "Month", 
   "Year"} // RepeatedTiming

{0.04, {{151., 25.}, {121., 25.}, {90., 25.}}}

Rasterize[CurrentDate[#], "RasterSize"] & /@ {"Day", "Month", 
   "Year"} // RepeatedTiming

{0.24, {{151, 26}, {121, 26}, {90, 26}}}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

*(After the clarification of the question, my original answer was not on target)*

An alternative to using [`ImageDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDimensions) is to use the "RasterSize" property with [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize):

```
dates = CurrentDate[Today,#]& /@ {"Day","Month","Year"};

Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"]& /@ dates
```

> {{148, 26}, {121, 26}, {90, 26}}

**Original answer**

You can use [`DateValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateValue) to determine the granularity of a [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject):

```
dates = CurrentDate[Today, #] & /@ {"Day", "Month", "Year"};

DateValue[#, "Granularity"]& /@ dates
```

> {"Day", "Month", "Year"}

Comment: Thanks. But meant size as in dimensions. Not size as in granularity. Clarified in question.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the size in pixels by using [`ImageDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDimensions.html) and [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html), like so:

```
Map[ImageDimensions@*Rasterize,
 CurrentDate[Today, #] & /@ {"Day", "Month", "Year"}]
(* {{148, 26}, {121, 26}, {90, 26}} *)
```

Comment: I am hoping there is a cleaner way than `Rasterize`.  (+1) for now.