# How to programmatically determine information about a DateObject

Tags: date-and-time

*(This question was inspired by my off-target answer to the question [How to get the size of a DateObject?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/166738/45431)). The answer was not obvious to me, so I think a question/answer for this would be useful)*

How can I programmatically determine properties like the time zone, calendar type and granularity of a [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject) without examining it's full form? For example:

```
date = CurrentDate[Now, "Week"];
date //InputForm
```

> DateObject[{2018, 2, 26}, "Week", "Gregorian", -8.]

Is there an accessor function that will return "Week", "Gregorian" and -8?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the accessor function [`DateValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateValue) to do this. For example:

```
DateValue[date, {"Granularity", "TimeZone", "CalendarType"}]
```

> {"Week", -8., "Gregorian"}