# Measure dimension of an expression without Rasterize

Tags: graphics, function-construction, image

Is there a method to measure (in pixel) width and height of an  expression without making it to an `Image` ?

I found a method for measuring width and height of an expression in this forum,
but it uses `Rasterize` and `ImageDimensions`.
It means it uses unnecessary CPU or RAM resources.
Also it is less intuitive. Moreover, I think MMA FrontEnd already knows the answer!

[image]

If you double click the expression, MMA FrontEnd highlights the boundary of the expression in blue.
It means MMA FrontEnd knows the answer before making it into an image.

Comment: Perhaps you can try `Rasterize[Style[x^2+y^2,40], "RasterSize"]`?

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be the document that suits my intention. Just before, I've tested with `Timing`. The test compares the performance of `"RasterSize"` option technique VS `Rasterize` + `ImageDimensions` technique, and there was little difference. So it may be appropriate to conclude there is no fast way to measure width/height without (essentially) making it into an image.

Comment: Perhaps not so useful a distinction, but I think it's the *front end* (rather than the kernel) that is responsible for visualization and that "knows the answer" you seek.

Comment: @MacroB, Thank you! I edited it.

Comment: It's not really fair to say that the front-end knows the size before "making it into an image": The front-end effectively had to rasterize the expression in order to display it in the first place

Comment: @LukasLang, the FrontEnd knows the dimensions of the boxes in points.  It also knows the density of the display that the notebook is on.  So yes, it knows the number of pixels.    It will never directly report them though, since they are not portable (even on the same machine).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the size of a DateObject?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166738/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-dateobject) Also: [How can I get the box size of a BoxObject?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158821/how-can-i-get-the-box-size-of-a-boxobject/166772).

Comment: Thank you, there was a way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

On my system ("13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)") the command that @kglr suggested runs in 0.025 seconds.

```
RepeatedTiming[Rasterize[Style[x^2 + y^2, 40], "RasterSize"]]
```

How much speed up is required? I wonder if you could perhaps describe your problem in full. I suppose you have to find out the size of millions of formulas. Maybe some latex (you can post your question of tex.stackexchange.com) solution can be of help?

Comment: Thank you, Domen has posted a link in the comment. That is close to my intention.