# Panel, Pane, and Framed Alignment - Clipped Images, Negative Margins, ContentPadding

Tags: output-formatting, gui-construction, boxes, alignment

I'm trying to tightly wrap some expressions in containers (could be `Panel`, `Pane`, maybe `Framed` in some cases -- it varies on the use-case) the way a normal expression cell's frame are laid-out.

That is, if you select a simple expression like `x`, you get the following:

[image]

Whereas, even with `PaneMargins` and `ImageMargins` set to `0`, selecting e.g. a `Pane` results in this:

[image]

One way to calculate the borders/margins between the inner expression and the bounding box of the expression when placed inside a container such as `Pane` is using `ImageBorders`.  That part is straightforward enough, and not the subject of this question (although I'd welcome more efficient methods than rasterizing and then using `ImageBorders`! EDIT: Found an alternative, see the end of this post.).

The subject of this question is: Can someone provide a general-case description, or link to documentation, for the alignment behavior of `Pane`, `Panel`, `Framed`, and any other bonus containers, with respect to options such as `Alignment` and `FrameMargins`?  Particularly, when `ImageSize` is less than what would be returned by `ImageSize@Rasterize@expr` and `FrameMargins` contains negative values, I find that the resulting output between the different containers varies quite a bit.

EDIT: As suggested by Carl Woll in a comment below, setting `ContentPadding->False` ought to solve this question.  However, I used that in my example below, and it didn't work.  I believe that wrapping e.g. a `Pane` in e.g. a `Grid` causes the `Pane`'s `ContentPadding` option to not be respected.  Maybe that behavior is the crux of this post.

It's easier to post a GIF animation exported from Mathematica than to explain much further.  On first inspection, it looks like there are two classes of containers: `Pane` and `Row` on the one hand, and `Framed` and `Panel` on the other.  But if you look closely, as glyphs "scroll into the inside of each container", the behavior is different between e.g. `Framed` and `Panel` when the margins are negative.  It makes getting a general-case solution tough when you're trying to tightly wrap expressions, but don't want them clipped.

Animation below:

[image]

And here is a version with the other margin dimension being animated:

[image]

REFERENCE:

The code used to generate the above plots is shown below:

```
MakeContainerSwatch[expr_, height_, alignment_] := 
 Module[{rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesFrame, rulesColor, 
   rulesColorPane, align, margins, pane1, pane2, pane3, framed1, 
   framed2, framed3, panel1, panel2, panel3, row1, row2, row3},
  rulesCommon = Sequence[
    ImageSize -> {Automatic, height},
    ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
    BaseStyle -> "Output"
    ];
  rulesPadding = Sequence[ContentPadding -> False];
  rulesFrame = Sequence[Frame -> True];
  rulesColor = Sequence[Background -> LightBlue];
  rulesColorPane = 
   Sequence[DefaultBaseStyle -> {Background -> LightBlue}];
  align[y_] = Alignment -> {Center, y};
  margins[align_] = FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, align};
  
  pane1 = 
   Pane[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColorPane, align[-1], 
    margins[alignment]];
  pane2 = 
   Pane[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColorPane, align[0], 
    margins[alignment]];
  pane3 = 
   Pane[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColorPane, align[1], 
    margins[alignment]];
  
  framed1 = 
   Framed[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColor, align[-1], 
    margins[alignment]]; 
  framed2 = 
   Framed[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColor, align[0], 
    margins[alignment]];
  framed3 = 
   Framed[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColor, align[1], 
    margins[alignment]];
  
  panel1 = 
   Panel[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColor, align[-1], 
    margins[alignment]];
  panel2 = 
   Panel[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColor, align[0], 
    margins[alignment]];
  panel3 = 
   Panel[expr, rulesCommon, rulesPadding, rulesColor, align[1], 
    margins[alignment]];
  
  row1 = Row[{expr}, rulesCommon, rulesFrame, rulesColor, align[-1], 
    margins[alignment]];
  row2 = Row[{expr}, rulesCommon, rulesFrame, rulesColor, align[0], 
    margins[alignment]];
  row3 = Row[{expr}, rulesCommon, rulesFrame, rulesColor, align[1], 
    margins[alignment]];
  
  {"pn", pane1, pane2, pane3, "fr", framed1, framed2, framed3, "pl", 
   panel1, panel2, panel3, "rw", row1, row2, row3}
  ]

sampleExpression = "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh";

dummyPane1 = Pane["*", BaseStyle -> "Output"];
dummyPane2 = Pane["*\n*\n*\n*\n*\n*\n*\n*\n", BaseStyle -> "Output"];

containerSwatch := With[
  {
   bottomLabel = StringTemplate["Bottom: `bot`"][<|"bot" -> bot|>],
   topLabel = StringTemplate["Top: `top`"][<|"top" -> top|>]
   },
  Grid[List /@ {
     Row@{
       Panel[
        ParametricPlot[{bot, y}, {y, 0, 10}, 
         PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {0, 10}}, PlotLabel -> bottomLabel, 
         Axes -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> Medium],
        ImageSize -> Scaled[0.49], Alignment -> Center],
       Panel[
        ParametricPlot[{top, y}, {y, 0, 10}, 
         PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {0, 10}}, PlotLabel -> topLabel, 
         Axes -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> Medium],
        ImageSize -> Scaled[0.49], Alignment -> Center]
       },
     Grid@List@{
        StyleHeading["Clipped: "],
        Splice@
         Prepend[dummyPane2]@
          MakeContainerSwatch[sampleExpression, 
           154 - 80, {bot, top}],
        StyleHeading[", Oversized: "],
        Splice@
         Prepend[dummyPane2]@
          MakeContainerSwatch[sampleExpression, 154 + 80, {bot, top}]
        }
     },
   ItemSize -> Full
   ]
  ]
containerSwatchAnimation1 = 
  Table[containerSwatch, {top, -40, 40, 20}, {bot, -40, 40, 2}];
containerSwatchAnimation2 = 
  Table[containerSwatch, {bot, -40, 40, 20}, {top, -40, 40, 2}];
Export["containerSwatchAnimation1.gif", 
 Flatten@containerSwatchAnimation1, ImageResolution -> 72/2]
Export["containerSwatchAnimation2.gif", 
 Flatten@containerSwatchAnimation2, ImageResolution -> 72/2]
```

EDIT: For posterity, here is a fast way to get the size you'd need to use to make a tightly-wrapped container.  Credit goes to this post by b3m2a1: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166772/76328

```
FrontEndExecute@
 GetBoundingBoxSizePacket@
  Cell[
   BoxData["aaaaaaa\na\na\na\na" // ToBoxes],
   "Output",
   PageWidth -> Infinity,
   ShowCellBracket -> False,
   CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
   ]
```

It's not the same as using `ImageRaster` and then the combination of `ImageDimensions` and `BorderDimensions`, but it's so much faster, and if I get the `ContentPadding` option (noted by Carl Woll below) working with `Grid`s, it'll be sufficient for my task-at-hand (a ragged `Grid` of `Row`s of `Pane`s of alternating colors, where the `Row`s are expected to line-wrap, but you want the `Pane`s to be the same height for aesthetics).

Comment: Try using `Pane[x,ContentPadding->False]`

Comment: @CarlWoll, it does indeed look like a `Pane` with `ContentPadding->False` is what I'm looking for, except for  one catch: I used `ContentPadding->False` in the above example, and it was ignored.  I wouldn't have dug further if you hadn't posted, so thanks.  It looks like the `ContentPadding` option does what I want, EXCEPT if you then nest the `Pane` in e.g. a `Grid`, in which case it gets ignored.  Any ideas on how to work around that?  Nesting the containers is a common use-case for me.  I may switch from using `Grid` to manually laying-out everything with `Row`s.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a smaller example where ContentPadding gets disabled? I don't have the time to see what's going on with your code.

Comment: @CarlWoll, I just posted an answer, but for posterity, here is a smaller example did not appear to respect `ContentPadding` at the time I tried it (it turns out that my `Spacings` specification was poor, and I did not specify `ItemSizes->{0,0}`: `Grid[List@List@Framed[".", ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, FrameMargins -> {{0, 0},{0, 0}}, ContentPadding -> False], Frame -> All, Spacings -> 0]`

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems that the issues you are trying to fix have nothing to do with spacing inside of Framed/Pane etc. (which is fixed with ContentPadding), but with the spacing that Grid adds around these objects.

Comment: In hindsight, I think you're right.  I only fumbled into `ContentPadding` along the way.  I was mostly using `Pane`s and `Panel`s during testing (and using background color to determine where the margins played-in).  I think I had gotten a "quasi-solution" working for them involving negative margins, but when I put them into an outer `Grid`, I noticed that there was now padding inside the colored areas in the `Pane`s and `Panel`s.  I'd have to go back and check my notes to remember exactly how I created the situation, but I think I have a solution now, so it's less pressing. ;-)

Comment: @CarlWoll, I was going back to give credit for the various StackOverflow posts I used, and it looks like you made one of them -- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/76328 ! Small world... Regarding your comment "using a single call to `ExportPacket` will be much quicker than using `graphicsInformation` on multiple `Graphics` objects", do you know of a way to use `ExportPacket` in this batch manner, but still get back granular size info for a collection of expressions?  I tried a `FrontEndExecute@Thread@ExportPacket@...` method, which worked, but gave no performance boost at all...

Comment: By threading, you have multiple ExportPacket objects instead of a single one. What I did was insert Annotation objects into a single expression, and then used one ExportPacket on that single expression. Annotation objects will generate region information which can be used to determine the size of the annotated object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again Carl Woll for the push in the right direction with pursuing `ContentPadding` further.  It turns out that `ContentPadding` **does** allow using a `Framed`/`Pane` to tightly wrap an expression, ***including* within a `Grid`, *if* you have a couple settings specified**.

### Solution:

First, I needed to specify `Spacings->{0,0}` explicitly, instead of using `Spacings->0`.  Easy to get this wrong... Secondly, to specify a minimum item size, you *simply use `ItemSize` directly*; that is, use `ItemSize->{0,0}`!  `ItemSize` behaves differently than what we may be accustomed to with `ImageSize` in other uses.  At least for a `Grid`, a setting of `{0,0}` does *not* mean "the item's size is nothing", it means that the item's *minimum* size is nothing.

### The working code follows:

```
testPane[expr_] := Pane[Style[expr, Red],
   ImageMargins -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}},
   FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
   ContentPadding -> False
   ];

testFramed[expr_] := Framed[Style[expr, Red],
   ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
   FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
   ContentPadding -> False
   ];

testTable[obj_] := Table[obj, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];

(* ItemSize ITSELF *IS* the MINIMUM item size *)
(* -- don't need to search for another option *)
testGrid[table_] := Grid[
  table,
  Frame -> All,
  Spacings -> {0, 0},
  ItemSize -> {0, 0}
  ]

Magnify[testGrid[testTable[testPane["a"]]], 5]
Magnify[testGrid[testTable[testFramed["a"]]], 5]

Magnify[testGrid[testTable[testPane[_]]], 5]
Magnify[testGrid[testTable[testFramed[_]]], 5]

Magnify[testGrid[testTable[testFramed["_jQ\""]]], 5]
Magnify[testGrid[testTable[testPane["_jQ\""]]], 5]

Magnify[testPane[_], 5]
Magnify[testFramed[_], 5]
```

### Output:

[image: Tight Grids 1]

[image: Tight Grids 2]

### Alternative:

To be thorough, I also pursued my other path, where I was trying to use negative margins to allow tight wrapping of an expression.  The crux of this method is coming up with ways to get the dimensions of an expression in the first place.  I came up with three methods, which may be useful for others.  I think that the slow `Rasterize`-based method is the only one that would do better than using `ContentPadding` (e.g. `ContentPadding` falls a bit short when you have very small expressions, like the `_` example shown above).  I included `AbsoluteTiming` information with each method.

At a high-level, and for keyword searching, the methods used were:

- `Rasterize`, `ImageDimensions`, `BorderDimensions`, and `ImageCrop`
- `FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[..., "BoundingBox"]`
- `FrontEndExecute@GetBoundingBoxSizePacket@...`
- `CellPrint`, `CellTags`, and `AbsoluteOptions`

### Alternative 1 - Raster-based method:

```
SetAttributes[RasterizeSwatch, HoldAllComplete]

RasterizeSwatch[expr_] :=
 
 Module[{imageSizeToPixelsCorrection, rasterRaw, dimsRasterRaw, 
   borderRasterRaw, dimsRasterRawNet, rasterCrop, dimsRasterCrop, 
   dimsRasterDirect, header1, header2, swatch},
  
  imageSizeToPixelsCorrection = 
   First["Scale" /. CurrentValue["ConnectedDisplays"]];
  
  (* Method 1 *)
  rasterRaw := Rasterize@HoldForm@expr;
  dimsRasterRaw := 
   ImageDimensions@rasterRaw/imageSizeToPixelsCorrection;
  borderRasterRaw := 
   BorderDimensions@rasterRaw/imageSizeToPixelsCorrection;
  (*dimsRasterRawNet:=Subtract@@{dimsRasterRaw,Map[Apply[Plus]]@
  borderRasterRaw};*)
  
  dimsRasterRawNet := dimsRasterRaw - Apply[Plus] /@ borderRasterRaw;
  
  (* Method 2 *)
  rasterCrop := ImageCrop@rasterRaw;
  dimsRasterCrop := 
   ImageDimensions@rasterCrop/imageSizeToPixelsCorrection;
  
  (* Method 3 *)
  
  dimsRasterDirect := 
   Rasterize[expr, "BoundingBox"]/imageSizeToPixelsCorrection;
  
  header1 = {Style["Raster-based Expression Size Info", Bold], 
    SpanFromLeft};
  header2 = Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"Operation", "Result", "Timing: 20x"};
  swatch = {
    header1,
    header2,
    {"rasterRaw", 
     FramedNoMargins@Image[rasterRaw, Magnification -> 2], 
     rasterRaw // TimeSequential[20]},
    {"dimsRasterRaw", dimsRasterRaw, rasterRaw = rasterRaw; 
     dimsRasterRaw // TimeSequential[20]},
    {"borderRasterRaw", borderRasterRaw, 
     borderRasterRaw // TimeSequential[20]},
    {"dimsRasterRawNet", dimsRasterRawNet, 
     dimsRasterRawNet // TimeSequential[20]},
    {"rasterCrop", 
     FramedNoMargins@Image[rasterCrop, Magnification -> 2], 
     rasterCrop // TimeSequential[20]},
    {"dimsRasterCrop", dimsRasterCrop, 
     dimsRasterCrop // TimeSequential[20]},
    {"dimsRasterDirect", dimsRasterDirect, 
     dimsRasterDirect // TimeSequential[20]}
    };
  
  Grid[swatch, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> Full, 
   Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
  ]
```

Alternative 2 - `FrontEndExute` Method:

```
FormatExportPacketBoundingBox[obj_] := 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &@{{Null, "Width", "Height"}, 
     Prepend[#[[1, 2]] - #[[1, 1]], "Net"], 
     Prepend[#[[1, 1]], "Padding"], 
     Prepend[#[[1, 2]], "Padded"], {"Baseline", #[[2]], 
      SpanFromLeft}} &@
  FrontEndExecute@ExportPacket[obj, "BoundingBox"]

Button["ExportPacket - BoundingBox", 
 Print@Style[#, "Output"] &@
  FormatExportPacketBoundingBox@NotebookSelection[]]

FormatGetBoundingBoxSizePacket[obj_] := 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &@
    Prepend[{"Width", "Baseline", "Height", "Net Height"}]@
     List@Append[#, #[[2]] + #[[3]]] &@
  First@FrontEndExecute@GetBoundingBoxSizePacket@obj

Button["GetBoundingBoxSizePacket", 
 Print@Style[#, "Output"] &@
  FormatGetBoundingBoxSizePacket@NotebookSelection[]]

FrontEndExecuteSwatch[expr_, frontEndFunction_, cellOpts___] :=
 
 Module[{exprHeldWithPane, boxes, boxesWithPane, cellFromBoxes, 
   cellFromBoxesWithPane, header1, header2, HideRules, swatch},
  
  exprHeldWithPane = PaneNoMarginsHeld@expr;
  
  boxes := ToBoxes@Unevaluated@expr;
  (*boxesWithPane=Replace[Unevaluated@ToBoxes@exprHeldWithPane,Hold[
  x_]\[Rule]HoldComplete@x,{1}];*)(*
  boxesWithPane=ToBoxes@Replace[
  exprHeldWithPane,Hold[x_]\[Rule]Unevaluated@x,{0}];*)
  
  boxesWithPane = 
   With[{x = Unevaluated @@ exprHeldWithPane}, ToBoxes@x];
  
  cellFromBoxes := Cell[BoxData@boxes, cellOpts];
  cellFromBoxesWithPane = Cell[BoxData@boxesWithPane, cellOpts];
  
  header1 = {Style[frontEndFunction, Bold], SpanFromLeft, 
    SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft};
  header2 = 
   Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"Step", "FullForm", "Displayed", 
     "Expression Size Info", "Timing: 20x"};
  
  HideRules[obj_] := 
   obj /. PaneOrPaneBox_[x__, y__Rule] -> 
     PaneOrPaneBox[x, RulesNotShown];
  
  swatch = {
    header1
    , header2
    , {"expr", HoldForm@FullForm@expr, HoldForm@expr, "N/A", "N/A"}
    , {"exprHeldWithPane", 
     HideRules@exprHeldWithPane /. Hold[x_] -> HoldForm@FullForm@x, 
     exprHeldWithPane /. Hold[x_] -> HoldForm@x, "N/A", "N/A"} (* 
    Replace with HoldForm, 
    but only after I fix the boxesWithPane issue *)
    , {"boxes", 
     FullForm@boxes, RawBoxes@boxes, "N/A", "N/A"}
    , {"boxesWithPane", HideRules@FullForm@boxesWithPane, 
     RawBoxes@boxesWithPane, "N/A", "N/A"}
    , {"cellFromBoxes", FullForm@cellFromBoxes, 
     RawBoxes@cellFromBoxes, frontEndFunction@cellFromBoxes, 
     frontEndFunction@cellFromBoxes // TimingTest[20]}
    , {"cellFromBoxesWithPane", 
     HideRules@FullForm@cellFromBoxesWithPane, 
     RawBoxes@cellFromBoxesWithPane, 
     frontEndFunction@cellFromBoxesWithPane, "N/A"}
    };
  
  Print@Style["CellPrint: cellFromBoxes", "Output"];
  CellPrint@cellFromBoxes;
  
  Print@Style["CellPrint: cellFromBoxesWithPane", "Output"];
  CellPrint@cellFromBoxesWithPane;
  
  g = Grid[swatch, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}(*,
    ItemSize\[Rule]{{Automatic,2\[Rule]Scaled[.4]},Automatic}*)];
  Style[g, "Output"] (* replace with just returning it *)
  ]
```

You can also issue `FrontEndExecute` with a list of `ExportPacket` results, which I read was supposed to be considerably quicker, but the timing looked to be within round-off error to me:

```
FrontEndExecute@Thread@ExportPacket[#, "BoundingBox"] &@
  Table[Cell@BoxData@ToBoxes[x + y/2], {i, 1, 20}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

### Alternative 3 - `CellSize` Method:

```
GetCellSize = Function[expr,
   Module[{cell, GetCellSizeTag},
    (* Can alternatively use an ExpressionCell *)
    
    cell[cellOpen_] := Cell[
      BoxData@
       With[{x = Unevaluated @@ PaneNoMarginsHeld[expr]}, ToBoxes@x]
      , "Output"
      , CellTags -> SymbolName@GetCellSizeTag
      , CellElementSpacings -> {"CellMinHeight" -> 0, 
        "ClosedCellHeight" -> 0}
      , CellMargins -> -2
      , CellFrame -> 0
      , ShowCellBracket -> False
      , Background -> LightRed
      , CellOpen -> cellOpen
      ];
    cellSize := 
     CellSize /. 
      AbsoluteOptions@
       First@Cells[CellTags -> SymbolName@GetCellSizeTag];
    
    Print@Style["GetCellSize - Unhidden CellPrint:", "Output", Bold];
    CellPrint@cell[True];
    
    Grid[
     {
      {Style["GetCellSize", Bold], SpanFromLeft},
      {"Width", "Height"},
      cellSize,
      {"Timing: 20x", SpanFromLeft},
      {(CellPrint@cell[False]; cellSize) // TimingTest[20], 
       SpanFromLeft}
      },
     Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}
     ]
    ]
   , HoldAllComplete
   ];
```

Usage:

```
RasterizeSwatch[1 + 1/2]
FrontEndExecuteSwatch[1 + 1/2, FormatExportPacketBoundingBox, "Output"]
FrontEndExecuteSwatch[
 1 + 1/2, FormatGetBoundingBoxSizePacket, "Output"]
GetCellSize[1 + 1/2]
```

Results:

[image: Raster Results]

[image: ExportBoundingBox Results]

[image: GetBoundingBoxSizePacket Results]

[image: CellSize Results]

I owe some credits to other StackOverflow posts for each of the three alternatives listed above; I'll come back and add some edits with links to the source posts, assuming I can find them.

### Utility Methods used above:

```
TimingTest[iMax_] = 
  Function[expr, 
   Do[expr, {i, 0, iMax}] // AbsoluteTiming // First // 
    NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 3}] &, HoldAllComplete];
TimeSequential[iMax_] = 
  Function[expr, (Do[expr, {i, 0, iMax - 1}]; expr = expr) // 
      AbsoluteTiming // First // NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 3}] &, 
   HoldAllComplete];

FramedNoMargins[expr_] := 
 Framed[expr, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0, 
  ContentPadding -> False]
PaneNoMargins[expr_] := 
 Pane[expr, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0, 
  ContentPadding -> False, 
  BaseStyle -> {Background -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[.3]]}]
PaneNoMarginsHeld = 
  Function[expr, Evaluate@Hold@Evaluate@PaneNoMargins@expr, 
   HoldAllComplete];
```