# SelectionMove within a GridBox?

Tags: front-end, grid-layouts

I want to interactively manipulate the contents of a [`GridBox`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridBox.html) using keyboard commands.  To approach this I need to control selection with something like [`SelectionMove`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SelectionMove.html) but I cannot figure out the right parameters.  How can I programmatically select individual elements and groups of elements within a GridBox?

Comment: Are you willing to wrap the elements at all? I think I can make a nice FE-friendly solution if I can wrap them in things to contain a `BoxID`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Pardon me for not replying, I had food poisoning.

Comment: oh no worries about that. I hope you are feeling better now.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Half way there; thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Finally got this working. It's a huge pain to find the current element in Mathematica, as we all know so that was basically what I needed to figure out how to find. But I did! And here's how I'm finding that:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/FENaming.wl"]
getCurrentPosition[tag_] :=
  Module[
   {
    nextObj =
     Replace[
      BoxObject[
       FENamed[_, tag <> "_gridElement"],
       {FE`BoxOffset -> FE`BoxParent[3]}
       ],
      Except[_BoxObject] :>
       EvaluationBox[]
      ],
    prevObj,
    body,
    inds
    },
   prevObj =
    Replace[
     FrontEndExecute@
      FrontEnd`ObjectChildren@
       FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ParentBox[nextObj],
     {
      {___, left_, nextObj, ___} :> left,
      {nextObj, ___, last_} :> last,
      _ -> None
      }
     ];
   If[prevObj === None,
    body = NotebookRead[prevObj];
    inds =
     FirstCase[nextObj,
      TagBox[__, 
        BoxID -> (s_String?(StringStartsQ[tag <> "_Position"]))] :>
       ToExpression@
        StringSplit[StringSplit[s, "_Position", 2][[-1]], ","],
      {-1, -1},
      6
      ];
    inds = inds - {0, 1},
    body = NotebookRead[prevObj];
    inds =
     FirstCase[body,
      TagBox[__, 
        BoxID -> (s_String?(StringStartsQ[tag <> "_Position"]))] :>
       ToExpression@
        StringSplit[StringSplit[s, "_Position", 2][[-1]], ","],
      {-1, -1},
      6
      ]
    ];
   inds
   ];
```

Then a very simple mover within a tagged grid and updated element wrapper:

```
moveAcrossTags[tag_, {dx_, dy_}] :=
 
 With[{pos1 = getCurrentPosition[tag]},
  NotebookLocate@
   FENamed[_, 
    tag <> "_Position" <>
     StringRiffle[
      Map[ToString, pos1 + {dx, dy}],
      ","
      ]
    ]
  ]

makeNamedGridElements[gridEls_, tag_String] :=
 MapIndexed[
  EventHandler[
    FENamed[
     FENamed[#, 
      tag <> "_Position" <> StringRiffle[Map[ToString, #2], ","]], 
     tag <> "_gridElement"],
    {
     "RightArrowKeyDown" :> moveAcrossTags["realGrid", {0, 1}],
     "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> moveAcrossTags["realGrid", {0, -1}],
     "DownArrowKeyDown" :> moveAcrossTags["realGrid", {1, 0}],
     "UpArrowKeyDown" :> moveAcrossTags["realGrid", {-1, 0}]
     }
    ] &,
  gridEls,
  {2}
  ]
```

Finally:

```
realGrid =
 Grid[
  makeNamedGridElements[#, "realGrid"] &@
   Partition[
    Thread@
     Graphics[
      Thread[{RandomColor[25], Disk[]}],
      ImageSize -> 25
      ], 
    5]
  ]
```

[image]

#### Original

Here's the start of a solution using the `FENamed` structure I defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167031/38205). We just attach a findable tag to each thing via the `BoxID` parameter, then we automatically get a clean way to find an element:

```
makeNamedGridElements[gridEls_, tag_String] :=
 MapIndexed[
  FENamed[#, tag <> Map[ToString, #2]] &,
  gridEls,
  {2}
  ]

realGrid =
 Grid@makeNamedGridElements[#, "realGrid_"] &@
  Partition[
   Thread@
    Graphics[
     Thread[{RandomColor[25], Disk[]}],
     ImageSize -> 25
     ], 
   5]
```

[image]

Once we have the *current* element it's easy to increment to the next, but finding the current one is admittedly beyond my ken right now.

Comment: This is quite elaborate and it will take some time to understand how this works.  I am not sure I will be able to apply it to what I had in mind, but I appreciate your work on this!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no worries if you can’t. My idea was simply to provide a tag to each grid element (via `BoxID`) and then use some undocumented front-end functions to find those elements (these things can also replace them, set/get `Options` on them and much much more).

Comment: Is `FENaming.wl` something you previously produced?  I do not recall its appearance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the core code has existed since I wrote that answer, but I just recently cleaned it up and made it into a proper package so that I could load it in this answe.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something crude like this could work:

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
GridBox[{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}] // DisplayForm

(* select col 2, row 2 -> 5 *)
SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell, 2];
SelectionMove[nb, Before, CellContents]
Do[SelectionMove[nb, Next, Character, 2], 5]
SelectionMove[nb, All, Word, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to only work with single character grid elements.  If I use `{"a", "b00", "c111"}` for the first row I get a different selection.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard After looking at it again, I don't think this approach is tenable.