# Deleting Print results

Tags: notebooks, output

While playing around with `$Pre` and `$Post` I created this very annoying piece of code:

```
$Post = If[# =!= 
 Null, (Print@"Are you sure you want to know the result?"; 
 Print@Row@{Button["Yes", Print@#], Button["No", Null]}), Null] &;
```

I have not yet found a use for it (other than possibly playing pranks on Mma newbies) but it led me to the following question:

How can one delete a certain cell that was created by `Print` (i.e. without selecting the cell manually)? And furthermore, how can one create a button that deletes itself upon being clicked (still evaluating the action)?

Ultimately I want the button to delete both itself and the `"Are you sure..."` cell.

I found out in the documentation that `PrintTemporary` objects can be deleted using `NotebookDelete`. Is there a similar way for `Print` cells? I think something similar to what I want could be done using `ChoiceDialog` and the like, but I'm really interested in deleting the `Print` cells.

Comment: To select "Print" cells, use something like the programmatic approaches [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14470/5) or [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9225/5) (modify to select a print cell). As for the button question, I'm certain it was asked previously (either here or on SO) and answered either by Heike or Sjoerd (if memory serves me right). I need to leave now, but perhaps this might be enough to get started (or searching)

Comment: I thought someone must have asked this, but I could't find anything. Thanks for the links. I'll look into them in detail tomorrow. It seems like tagging the cells as in the second link should work for me.

Comment: @rm-rf. Regarding the button question: were you thinking of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14242/self-referential-list-or-table-of-buttons)

Comment: @m_goldberg That seems to be the one (I must've misremembered the users). There's also [this very relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6387132) on self-destructing buttons and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5908111) on self-destructing input cells, both of which can possibly be modified for the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A self-destructing cell that creates a self-destructing button which deletes all cells generated by `Print`:
(credit: Sasha, jVincent and Yves Klett for the ideas in answers/comments in the linked Q/As)

```
Print[Button["Delete Print-generated cells & disappear", 
 NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle]; NotebookDelete[]]];
 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]; NotebookDelete[];
```

[image]

After evaluating the cell

```
 NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle];
```

[image]

Note the `CellStyles` (highlighted) of an ordinary `Output` cell and that of the one produced by `Print`.

After evaluating

```
Print[Button["Delete Print-generated cells & disappear", 
 NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle]; NotebookDelete[]]];
 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell]; NotebookDelete[];
```

[image]

After the clicking the button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the help provided in the comments I have achieved almost exactly what I want using this code:

```
$Post = If[# =!= Null,
    CellPrint[
     TextCell["Are you sure you want to know the result?",
      CellTags -> "tag"]];
    CellPrint[ExpressionCell[
      Row@{
        Button["Yes",
         NotebookLocate["tag"]; NotebookDelete[]; 
         CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Output"]]],
        Button["No", NotebookLocate["tag"]; NotebookDelete[]]}, 
      CellTags -> "tag"]]] &;
```

It uses `CellPrint` instead of `Print` and tags the created cells to locate and delete them afterwards. The only thing that does not quite work as I expected is that no matter where a cell is evaluated, after clicking the "Yes" button, the result is always printed at the very end of the notebook, and not where the actualy output should be.