# How to write Mma notebook input that modifies itself?

Tags: front-end, input-forms

Is there a straightforward way to reference and modify a cell from within itself?

This is a little outside the ordinary use case and certainly not good practice, but I would like to execute an input cell in a notebook causing the kernel to perform some action and output results and then replace or delete the current input cell and it's output.

I currently use some trivial cleanup code at the end of a routine to process data and after it has run once it isn't useful to have around and I end up deleting it manually. This got me thinking, how can I get Mathematica to do this automatically? Maybe it's possible to build it into the notebook style? Something like:

> Format --> Style --> RunOnceAndDeleteInput

Comment: is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17985/125) relevant/useful?

Comment: @kguler Yes, `NotebookDelete` seems to be useful for clobbering cells and output, but it's not clear to me how to reference an input cell from within itself.

Comment: You can use `EvaluationCell` to _reference an input cell from within itself_ . So a cell with the lines `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell];NotebookDelete[]` finds and deletes itself.

Comment: @kguler Cool. This: `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],All,EvaluationCell];NotebookDelete[];` works great for clobbering a cell.

Comment: @kguler looks like `NotebookWrite` can be used with the cell selector code and you've got everything you need for arbitrary self-modifying cells.

Comment: dyonis, you might consider self-answering your question along those lines.

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/how-to-create-a-notebook-element-that-can-replace-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *Mathematica* version 9 onward, the following expressions are possible...

To delete the current cell:

```
NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]]
```

To replace the current cell with a text cell:

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], Cell["New Content", "Text"]]
```

To replace the current cell with an input cell containing an arbitrary expression:

```
NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[a + b/c], "Input"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Self-deleting cell with output:

```
Print@"arbitrary output";
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellGroup];
NotebookDelete[];
```

Modifying an input cell:

```
Print@"arbitrary text";
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, CellContents];
Do[SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Word], {i, 7}];
Paste[Defer[Print@"... bonus text!";]];
```