# Delete Cell Inside of Module

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, output-formatting, cells

I want to print a dynamic output while some code is running and then automatically delete it when when the output is done. PrintTemporary is not quite what I am looking for -- I want the output to be deleted from inside the module rather than when the cell is done evaluating because I want to evaluate several modules in the same cell. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
test[steps_]:=Module[{},
    n=0;
    Print["% Complete: ",Dynamic[n*100/steps]];
    For[n=0,n<steps,n++,
        (*CODE RUNS*)
    ];
    (*Delete Output Cell*)
]
```

I want to explicitly delete the output cell created when running `test`, but cannot find the commands to do so. All I have seen on stackexchange is how to delete ALL output cells or how to print temporarily, which I do not want.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like:

```
test[steps_] := Module[{}, n = 0;
  Print["% Complete: ", Dynamic[n*100/steps]];
  For[n = 0, n < steps, n++, Pause[1]];
  NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle]; 
  NotebookDelete[]]
```

[image]

See also: [A self-deleting button to delete Print cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17985/125)