# Is it possible to overwrite a button output?

Tags: output, button

For example, if I have this basic button

`Button["Sum",  Print[2 + 2]]`

is it possible to overwrite the same output without creating a new one and have a single 4 printed out?

Comment: You can use Dynamic or NotebookWrite, depends on the context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a notebook element that can replace itself?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/how-to-create-a-notebook-element-that-can-replace-itself)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the result to a variable and access the variable dynamically, like:

```
Button["Sum 2+2", x = 2 + 2]
Button["Sum 2+5", x = 2 + 5]
Dynamic@x
```

Output:

> x
>
> (press first button)
>
> 4
>
> (press second button)
>
> 7